# ¿ How to check the number of characters of an int variable?

Tags: java

I want the user to type a phone number on my keyboard, and if the number has more than 9 characters, print it out.

```
System.out.println("your number :");
    int number = in.nextInt();

    if(number > 9) {
        System.out.println("the number has 10 or more characters");
    }
```

I do it like this but it doesn't work

Comment: `Math.log(number)/Math.log(10)` (math). In code `int len = (int) (1 + (Math.log(number) / Math.log(10)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
System.out.println("your number :");
String number = in.nextLine();

if(number.length() > 9) {
    System.out.println("the number has 10 or more characters");
}
```

**Notes:**

1. `Scanner::nextLine` returns a `String` whose length can be calculated using `String::length`.
2. Most likely, you are not going to use this number for any mathematical calculation e.g. addition, subtraction etc. and therefore `String` type is most appropriate for it. Just in case, you need to convert it into an `int` or `long` value, you can use `Integer.parseInt(number)` or `Long.parseLong(number)` respectively.

Comment: ok, by the way I like this version better. in Spanish they are somewhat rigid

Comment: You should probably do String number = in.nextLine().trim(); to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the int value and use

```
Integer.toString(yourInt)
```

and then use

```
yourString.length()
```